# Building Erlang applications for the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, erlang, cloud, distributed

I'm working on a socket server that'll be deployed to AWS and so far we have the basic OTP application set up following a structure similarly to the sample project in [Erlang in Practice](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-kserl/erlang-in-practice), but we wanted to avoid having a global message router because that's not going to scale well.

Having looked through the OTP design guide on [Distributed Applications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/distributed_applications.html) and the corresponding chapters ([Distribunomicon](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distribunomicon) and [Distributed OTP](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distributed-otp-applications)) in [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content) it seems the built-in distributed application mechanism is geared towards on-premise solutions where you have known hostnames and IPs and the cluster configuration is determined ahead of time, whereas in our intended setup the application will need to scale dynamically up and down and the IP addresses of the nodes will be random.

Sorry that's a bit of a long-winded build up, my question is whether there are design guidelines for distributed Erlang applications that are deployed to the cloud and need to deal with all the dynamic scaling?

Thanks,

Comment: Not for erlang, but for elasticsearch, we built a job that constantly monitors the IPs of who is in the cluster, and modifies a local config file and stops/starts the service on that box when it detects a change. I would assume erlang has something built in for this, but perhaps its a fallback plan/idea

Comment: It's trivial to add a node to an existing cluster in Erlang but it doesn't fit with the way distributed OTP application is set up based on what I've read so far - distributed OTP application provides built-in mechanisms for auto-failover, etc. which are useful but documentation points to the need to hardcode mandatory nodes in the app config

Answer (score 6):

There are a few possible approaches:

- In Erlang and OTP in Action, one method presented is to use one or two central nodes with known domains or IPs, and have all the other nodes connect to this one to discover each other
- Applications like https://github.com/heroku/redgrid/tree/logplex require having a central redis node where all Erlang nodes register themselves instead, and do membership management
- Third party services like Zookeeper and whatnot to do something similar
- Whatever else people may recommend

Note that unless you're going to need to protect your communication, either by switching the distribution protocol to use [SSL](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html), or by using AWS security groups and whatnot to restrict who can access your network.

Comment: Thanks Fred, no.1 is easy to do using EC2's elastic IP, worth considering. Alternatively we also thought it's possible to hardcode an auto scaling group name in the app config, so that when an instance starts up it'll query ASG for instances and ping all the nodes besides itself to get connected.

Comment: But after you have discovered other nodes and joined the cluster, how do you handle failover scenarios etc.? I'm guessing the tools (failover + takeover) you get out of the box with distributed OTP won't work in this case?

Comment: They likely won't, no. They usually assume well-known nodes in a strict hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just learning Erlang so can't offer any practical advice of my own but it sounds like your situation might require a "Resource Discovery" type of approach as i've read about in Erlang & OTP in Action.

Erlware also have an application to help with this: https://github.com/erlware/resource_discovery

Comment: Thanks, I'll get the book and have a look

Answer (score 0):

Other stupid answers in addition to Fred's smart answers include:

1. Using Route53 and targetting a name instead of an IP
2. Keeping an IP address in AWS KMS or AWS Secrets Manager, and connecting to that (nice thing about this is it's updatable without a rebuild)
3. Environment variables: scourge or necessary evil?
4. Stuffing it in a text file in an obscured, password protected s3 bucket
5. VPNs
6. Hardcoding and updating the build in CI/CD

I mostly do #2